# CSS - Float push down issue, icons displayed in stairs like layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

Encountering a CSS push down problem, been searching for fix but not able to find out what exactly is the problem. All the icons are displayed in a stairs-like layout. Need your help in fixing this.

HTML

```
<div style="/*float: left; width:153.6px;" */ class="footerStyles">
  <h4 style=" margin: 0; font-size: 100%;">CONNECT</h4>
  <a href="#" class="email connectWith"></a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" class="twitter connectWith"></a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" class="facebook connectWith"></a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" class="googleplus connectWith"></a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.connectWith{
    /*background-position: left center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    padding-top: 8px; 
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    padding-left: 40px;*/ 
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
/* email    ---------- */
.email{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url("http://www.browsealoud.com/images/browsealoud/plus/uk/firefox.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.email:hover{
    background-position: 0 50px;
}
/* twitter  ---------- */
.twitter{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url("http://www.browsealoud.com/images/browsealoud/plus/uk/firefox.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.twitter:hover{
    background-position: 0 50px;
}
/* facebook ---------- */
.facebook{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: -9999px;
    background-image: url("http://www.browsealoud.com/images/browsealoud/plus/uk/firefox.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.facebook:hover{
    background-position: 0 50px;
}
/* google+  ---------- */
.googleplus{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: -9999px;
    background-image: url("http://www.browsealoud.com/images/browsealoud/plus/uk/firefox.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.googleplus:hover{
    background-position: 0 50px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ4UU/)

Comment: And how _should_ they be displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want them side-by-side, then you should remove the `<br />`s you have. That's what's causing the stair effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ4UU/1/

If you want them to display one underneath the other, then you shouldn't have it floated at all.

Comment: Removed my answer... you beat me to it @setek!

Comment: @jameslafferty haha it's like the wild wild west!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to include property `clear:both` (or left, right).

Answer (score 2):

Take out `<br>` element after each `<a>` tag and your problem will vanish. You are floating a elements left, but they are also separated with `<br>` tags that have some default margin and padding.